# After accidentally deleting aws classic load balancer, k8s still points ingress addresses to it

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

After accidentally deleting a classic ELB that my k8s ingress resources were using, when I create new ingresses and run `kubectl get ing`, I still see the old address being used

```bash
kubectl get ing

NAME             CLASS    HOSTS           ADDRESS                                     PORTS     AGE
my-ingress-name  <none>   my-host.domain  old-elb-address.region-1.elb.amazonaws.com  80        2y1d
# etc...
```

How can I "refresh" k8s to either create a new elb or recognize a new one I've created manually via aws console?

I've tried creating new ELB manually to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to manually delete the nginx controller service (which was living in a different namespace) and then re-apply its manifest file in order to recreate it.

My notes:

- `kubectl get ns` to list the namespaces
- `kubectl get svc -n my-ingress-nginx-namespace`
- `kubectl delete svc my-ingress-nginx-controller-svc -n my-ingress-nginx-namespace` to manually delete the service
- `kubectl apply -f path/to/my-ingress-nginx-controller-svc-manifest.yaml` to create the service again

After running the above, I found that a new ELB was created in AWS console and was able to finish my configuration work from there.